# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

i am trying to update my data from webservice to my database. But once i click invoke in the web service page , and run to this command:"command1.Connection.Open();" i will receive this error message :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is my code:

```
  [WebMethod]
        public void UpdateParticulars(string Name, string CLass, string NRIC, float AmountSpent)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ncpConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Student set Name=@Name, Class=@CLass,StallNo=@StallNo,AmountSpent=@AmountSpent WHERE NRIC = '" + NRIC + "'");

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", CLass);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountSpent", AmountSpent);

                command1.Connection.Open();
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Change this command1.Connection.Open(); to conn.Open();

Comment: having this error : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable &quot;@StallNo&quot;.

Comment: you have added that paramater. Add this command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo", "");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass your `SqlConnection` as argument to `SqlCommand` constructor.

```
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
```

Also change your query to be fully parametrized (and you are missing @StallNo parameter):

```
"UPDATE Student set Name=@Name, Class=@CLass,StallNo=@StallNo,AmountSpent=@AmountSpent WHERE NRIC = @NRIC"

command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", CLass);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NRIC", NRIC);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountSpent", AmountSpent);
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo", ""); //missing parameter
```

Comment: i got this errror: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable &quot;@StallNo&quot;.

Comment: I pointed that out in my answer `(and you are missing @StallNo parameter):` must add this `command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StallNo", ""); //missing parameter` with proper value.

Answer (score 0):

use command1.Connection=conn;
conn.Open();

Before executing ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line

```
conn.open();
```

instead of

```
command1.Connection.Open();
```